# Python add quotes to comma-delimited string?

Tags: python

Im using python3, 
How can i make this string :

```
a = "a,b"
```

To:

```
a = "'a','b'"
```

Comment: `a = ','.join('\'{0}\''.format(v) for v in a.split(','))`

Comment: There are many wrong things that need this. Can you explain why you're doing this transformation?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = "a,b"
>>> ','.join(f"'{e}'" for e in s.split(','))
"'a','b'"
```

Comment: nice usage of f-String. Note that it is only supported starting from Python3.6